# How to update UI when request server for new list SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to update my product list in UI when I select different sort type in Menu selection.When i select new sort type im sending sort id to server and server should give me new product list and with that list my UI should update. Somehow my UI is not updating I don't know why.

This is my ViewModel

```
class ProductListViewModel : ObservableObject {


@Published var sortListArray : [ProductListSortAndFilterList] = []

var productList = PassthroughSubject<ProductListResponse,Never>()

var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

var storeResponse = InfoResponse()

var currentPage = 1

var perPage = 12


func getProductListResponse(typeId : String , type : String, sortId : String) {
    
    let tsoftFilter = """
        [{"key" : "\(type)", "value" : "\(typeId)"}] 
        """
    
    print("tsoft filter is \(tsoftFilter)")
    
    print("sort id is \(sortId)")
    
    let serviceParams = [
        
        "store_id" : Config.productListId,
        "page" : currentPage,
        "per_page" : perPage,
        "tsoft_filters" : "\(tsoftFilter)",
        "sort" : Int(sortId)
        
        
    ] as [String : AnyObject]
    
    
    getProductList(params: serviceParams).sink { (error) in
        
        print("ERROR İS -> \(error)")
        
    } receiveValue: { (ProductListResponse) in
        
        
        self.productList.send(ProductListResponse)
        self.sortListArray.append(contentsOf: ProductListResponse.data?.extra ?? [])
        
    }.store(in: &cancellable)
    
}
```

}

This is my View.

```
struct ProductListView: View {

@ObservedObject var productViewModel = ProductListViewModel()
@State var productListArray : [ProductListDataArray] = []
@State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
@State var isAnimating : Bool = true
@State var isSelected : Bool = true
@State var isLoading : Bool = false
@State var paginationIndicator : Bool = false
@State var isFinish : Bool = true
@State var memberListFull : Bool = false
@State var isLoadingPage = false
@State var popUpOpened : Bool = false
@State var sortListArray : [ProductListSortAndFilterList] = []
@State var sortId : String = ""


var typeId : String
var type : String


var body: some View {
    
    ZStack{
        
        ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
        
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators : true){
            
            
            if isSelected == false {
                
                SortMenuPickerView(sortClicked: $popUpOpened, sortListArray: sortListArray, function: {getProductList()},sortId : $sortId)
                
                
            }
            
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 5), count:2), spacing:10 ) {
                
                ForEach(productListArray , id:\.uid) { item in // MARK: Optional typed changed
                    
                    ZStack{
                        
                        CatalogBackgroundView()
                        
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: item.image?.medium ?? ""))
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat(item.imageRatio ?? 0.6),contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.5,height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 6)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.083, trailing: 0))
                            
                            
                            .onAppear {
                                
                                loadMoreContentIfNeeded(currentItem: item)
                                
                            }
                        
                        
                        Text(item.title ?? "")
                            .font(.custom("DM Sans", size: 14))
                            .frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.3)
                            .lineLimit(2)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.14, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        
                        
                        
                        if item.isDiscountActive == 0 || item.isDiscountActive == nil || item.isDiscountDisplay == 0 {
                            
                            Text("\(item.priceSell ?? 0 , specifier: "%.2f" ) \(item.targetCurrency ?? "") +VAT")
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.24, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            
                            
                        } else {
                            
                            HStack(){
                                
                                VStack() {
                                    
                                    Text("% \(item.discountPercent ?? 1)")
                                        .font(.custom("DM Sans", size: 11))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)))
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.060))
                                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                                    
                                    
                                    Text("\(item.priceNotDiscounted ?? 0 , specifier: "%.2f") \(item.targetCurrency ?? "") " )
                                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                                        .strikethrough()
                                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)))
                                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                                    
                                }
                                
                                
                                Text("\(item.priceSell ?? 0 , specifier: "%.2f" ) \(item.targetCurrency ?? "") ")
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.013, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                                
                                
                            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.23, leading: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.06, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                        if item.inStock == false {
                            
                            OutOfStockTag()
                            
                        }
                        
                        if item.isNewProduct == 1 {
                            
                            NewProductTag()
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    .onAppear {
        
        if isFinish{
            
            getProductList()
            
        }
        
    }
    .onDisappear {
        
        isFinish = false
        
        productViewModel.currentPage = 0
        
    }
    
}

func getProductList() {
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        productViewModel.productList.sink { (ProductListResponse) in
            
            isSelected = false
            isAnimating = false
            
            productViewModel.currentPage += 1
            
            productListArray.append(contentsOf: ProductListResponse.data?.data ?? [])
            sortListArray.append(contentsOf: ProductListResponse.data?.extra ?? [])
            
         
            
        }.store(in: &cancellable)
        
    }
    
    productViewModel.getProductListResponse(typeId: typeId, type: type, sortId: sortId)
    
}
```

This is where I select Menu and passing sort id .

struct SortMenuPickerView : View {

```
@State private var selection = 0
@Binding var sortClicked : Bool
@ObservedObject var productListViewModel = ProductListViewModel()
@State var sortListArray : [ProductListSortAndFilterList]
var function: () -> Void
@Binding var sortId : String

var body : some View {
    
    HStack(alignment: .center){
        
        Spacer()
        
        Menu {
            
            ForEach(sortListArray,id:\.id){ item in
                if item.id == "sort" {
                    
                    ForEach(item.sortList ?? [],id:\.id) { data in
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            sortId = (data.id ?? "")
                            self.function()
                            print("selected item is : \(data.id!)")
                            
                            
                        }) {
                            
                            Text(data.name ?? "")
                                .tag(data.id)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } label: {
            
            
            SortView()
            
            
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you have your **sortListArray** listed using the state wrapper.

State is the simplest source of truth your app can have. It is designed to contain simple value types, such as Ints, Strings, and Bools. It is not designed for more complex, reference types, such as any classes or structs you define yourself and use within your app.

Because you're using a complex, reference type, the value of state itself never changes. The @State property wrapper has no idea because it is only watching the variable state, not any of its properties. To SwiftUI, because it is only watching state, it has no idea that num has changed, and so never re-renders the view.

I wasn't looking too closely at your code, but I think it would be worthwhile spending some time understanding the wrappers a bit more since I see that you reinitialize ProductListViewModel in your child view. If you want more info, take a look at [this article](https://purple.telstra.com/blog/swiftui---state-vs--stateobject-vs--observedobject-vs--environme). What I said above is just some notes from that article.

My suggestion would be to pass your observed object ProductListViewModel to the SortMenuPickerView and use the sortedListArray on that instead of the sortedListArray you create in the ProductListView

```
SortMenuPickerView(sortClicked: $popUpOpened, productListViewModel: productListViewModel, function: {getProductList()},sortId : $sortId)

struct SortMenuPickerView : View {

@State private var selection = 0
@Binding var sortClicked : Bool
@ObservedObject var productListViewModel : ProductListViewModel
var function: () -> Void
@Binding var sortId : String

var body : some View {
    
    HStack(alignment: .center){
        
        Spacer()
        
        Menu {
            
            ForEach(productListViewModel.sortListArray,id:\.id){ item in
                if item.id == "sort" {
// the rest
    }
}
```